# Post JSON with cURL doesn't work

Tags: php, json, rest, api, curl

I know this question was asked many times but I didn't find an answer to it.
I have this cURL call:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$post_data = "{'application_token':'aksjnhksdbfjsbkdjfkjdhf','client_company_name':'TEST COMPANY','client_email':'test@test.ro','client_phone_number':'012000000','client_cui':'1234567','client_chosen_option':'BEST OPTION','registration_number':'36230'}";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.ro/test/api/test');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), 1);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($result);
```

And in my test method I have this:

```
function testAction () {
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
         return json_encode(
                [
                    'response_type' => 'success',
                    'response_message' => 'SUCCESS'
                ]
            );
     } else {
         return json_encode(
                [
                    'response_type' => 'error',
                    'response_message' => 'ERROR'
                ]
            );
     }
}
```

And my result output is always the error one. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: check what is the method coming for $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

Comment: So, I managed to fix my problem, but now when I want to get the parameters, all are empty. How can I get the parameters?

Comment: what is the fix you made? try to debug the posted data

Comment: It was a spelling mistake, I wrote REQUEST_METOD. But now the problem is when I wrote var_dump($_POST) displays an empty array.